# Google not showing the preferred geolocalized domain

Tags: google, search, language

I have a multi-language / multi-domain website. I have configured every sitemap for each domain and language. In Google Webmaster Tools, I have indicated the preferred region for each domain. I also use `hreflang` with the format "language-country". Even so, I will only obtain results from my `.com` domain, and after that, only a few from my .country domain (for example `.es`), even if I try different regions and languages by using the hl and gl parameters of Google search.

What are the best steps for correctly configuring the metadata, sitemap, robots, and Google Webmaster Tool parameters to get the sites listed in search results as I wish? How can I check correctly what is shown to Google users in different countries and default languages?

Comment: I think you'd need to share links to your sites. There are many possible explanations; being able to look for ourselves is the most efficient way to help you.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible, as the domains do not belong to me but to my clients, and I guess they will not be happing of having it listed. I am using approach by Evgeniy and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by using the hl and gl parameters of Google search

it is by far not enough to get localized search results. use something like http://isearchfrom.com/ or http://usearchfrom.com/

> I have configured every sitemap for each domain and language. In Google Webmaster Tools, I have indicated the preferred region for each domain. I also use hreflang with the format "language-country".

- Are all pages at all domains contain hreflang relations?
- Are all domains have textual content in own languages?

You should answer both questions with *yes*.